# Fastest Principal Component Analysis PCA algorithm for high dimensional data?

Tags: data-mining

I would like to perform a Principal Component Analysis on a dataset composed of approximately 40 000 samples, each sample displaying about 10 000 features.

Using Matlab princomp function takes ages ... What would be the fastest algorithm ? How long would it take on a i7 dual core / 4GB Ram ?

Thanks for your support

Comment: polymerase chain activity? putrid child adenoids? There's too many TLAs these days...

Comment: I have tried python scikit-learn PCA function and this algorithm http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21524-principal-component-analysis/content/pca.m

Comment: What is the domain of the problem? Can you avoid PCA in the first place?

Comment: The domain is supervised learning. I don't like to feed my neural net or else with such a large number of features... but I may be wrong

Comment: you can try randomized pca \ probalistic pca

Answer (score 0):

crosspost of this: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-calculate-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-general-matrix/7487#7487

There has been some good research on this recently. The new approaches use "randomized algorithms" which only require a few reads of your matrix to get good accuracy on the largest eigenvalues. This is in contrast to power iterations which require several matrix-vector multiplications to reach high accuracy.

You can read more about the new research here:

http://math.berkeley.edu/~strain/273.F10/martinsson.tygert.rokhlin.randomized.decomposition.pdf

http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4061

This code will do it for you:

http://cims.nyu.edu/~tygert/software.html

https://bitbucket.org/rcompton/pca_hgdp/raw/be45a1d9a7077b60219f7017af0130c7f43d7b52/pca.m

http://code.google.com/p/redsvd/

https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/stochastic-singular-value-decomposition.html

If your language of choice isn't in there you can roll your own randomized SVD pretty easily; it only requires a matrix vector multiplication followed by a call to an off-the-shelf SVD.